# MySQL не записывает слова кириллицей

Tags: java, mysql

Не могу найти подходящий ответ в интернете. Не подходят.

Метод, который кодключается к таблице выглядит так:

```
Connection connect(){
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mainDb";    
            String username = BotConfig.DATABASE_USER;
            String password = BotConfig.DATABASE_PASSWORD;
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Метод добавления данных в таблицу выглядит так:

```
   int insertNewUser(long id, long garden_id, String name, String surname){
        try {
            connection = connect();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `garden_id`, `name`, `surname`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

            preparedStatement.setLong(1, id);
            preparedStatement.setLong(2, garden_id);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, name);
            preparedStatement.setNString(4, surname);

            int result = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            connection.close();

            System.out.println(result);

            return result;
        } catch (Exception ignore){
            ignore.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

метод по созданию таблицы:

```
boolean createTable(){
        try {
            String query = "create table users" +
                "(" +
                "id bigint not null," +
                "garden_id bigint null," +
                "name varchar(255)," +
                "surname varchar(255)," +
                "primary key (id));";
            connection = connect();
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            boolean result = statement.execute(query);
            connection.close();
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Я понимаю, что дело в MySQL (помимо кода), но все-таки проблема не решается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге я попробовал разные способы и сработал вот такой, взятый с из ответа с вот [этого форума](https://ru-java.livejournal.com/1000711.html):

> при любом подключении сразу после выбора базы (за исключением
>   создания): SET CHARASTER SET 'utf8'; SET
>   collation_connection='utf8_general_ci';
>
> при создании базы данных кодировку указывать не обязательно CREATE
>   DATABASE database_name;
>
> при создании таблиц - обязательно CREATE TABLE table_name ( ... )
>   DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
>
> естественно не следует забывать что в самом приложении символы и файлы
>   с кодом должны быть в utf8

Как я и ожидал, проблема была не в самом коде, а еще при создании таблицы.

В случае, если указанный выше ответ не сработает - оставьте его.

Попробуйте использовать следующие вещи:

## Вариант 1:

Некоторые [предлагают решение](https://coderwall.com/p/rvduyw/jdbc-inserting-unicode-utf-8-characters-into-mysql) с указанием в конце URL **useUnicode=yes** и **charsetEncoding=UTF-8**:
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASE_NAME`?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

## Вариант 2:

Взято с сайта [dev.mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)

Написать в MySQL консоли -

```
SET NAME 'utf8';
```

## Вариант 3:

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202205/how-to-make-mysql-handle-utf-8-properly).

Написать в MySQL консоли -

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Надеюсь, вам это поможет